# Javascript Remove an array element and reorder the remaining elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with a fixed length of 6.

I want to remove the first element from the array, then shift all the elements left by 1, but the length of the array should remain as 6 (the 6th position of the array can be undefined)

I tried using `splice` but the array length was reduced to 5 which is not what I want to happen.

What is the best approach to achieve the above?

Comment: do you have an example and what you have tried?

Comment: Use the delete operator. It will remove the item, and replace it with undefined, making sure the length does not change.

Comment: do you like to mutate the array to keep the same object reference? or is a new array fine? do you have a typed array? what have you tried already, what does not work? why is the length important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.slice` (which does not mutate the original array unlike `splice`) to take a copy of the array from the 1st position.

Then use `Array.from` to get a new array from the copy and mention the `length` property value of the old array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const newArr = Array.from({length: arr.length, ...arr.slice(1)});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the first element, then push `undefined`, as shown below:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

array.shift()
array.push(undefined)

console.log(array)
```